# strace output extract file names from double quotes

Tags: regex, filter, output, strace

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/lib/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/lib/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
......................
```

The above lines are the typical output of strace command run with file option.

I want to filter out the file names ( with / without directory ) within double quotes from the above output...e.g My requirement is to get following list.

```
/etc/ld.so.cache
/lib/libselinux.so.1
 ..........
```

How to get get the above filtered out file names using regular expression handling utilities ( grep / sed / awk / etc..) in linux ?

Comment: What regex tool are you using?

Comment: I know preliminary usage of grep.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `grep`:

```
grep -oP '"\K[^\n"]+(?=")' file
/etc/ld.so.cache
/lib/libselinux.so.1
/lib/librt.so.1
/lib/libacl.so.1
/lib/libc.so.6
/lib/libdl.so.2
/lib/libpthread.so.0
/lib/libattr.so.1
```

This regex searches a double quote and then resets the match result using `\K`. It finds text between double quotes using `[^\n"]+` followed by a lookahead `(?=")` to make sure there is a matching double quote on the other side.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP4zP7/1)

Comment: Thanks anubhava! Can you briefly explain the filtering part ?

Comment: Also see my demo link in the answer.

Comment: The following worked from me when using `strace -f -e open,execve -o strace.log <cmd>`: `grep -oP '^(\d+\s+\w+\(")\K([^"]+(?="))' strace.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and usable :

```
$ strace -f -e trace=file  true 2>&1 | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
/usr/bin/true
/etc/ld.so.preload
/etc/ld.so.cache
/usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

As far of the output of the `strace` command is composed of files in double quotes, I tell [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (with `-F`) to use it as a delimiter, then print the second column based on the splitted string for each lines.

Comment: Thanks sputnick! Can you briefly explain the filtering part ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`, e.g.

```
grep ^open in.txt | grep -o '".\+[^"]"'
```

To filter out the double quotes, add `tr -d '"'`.

And here is one-liner with `strace` (change `php` to your command name):

```
strace -fe trace=file -p $(pgrep -n php) 2>&1 | grep ^stat | grep -o '".\+[^"]"'
```